# In SpriteKit when sound is being played it messes with accelerometer

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I have an issue whereby I am moving the character based on the accelerometer data using the following code in the update function as follows:

```
        let currentX = self.player.position.x

        if motionManager.isAccelerometerAvailable == true {

            motionManager.startAccelerometerUpdates(to: OperationQueue.current!, withHandler: {

                data, error in

                self.destX = currentX + CGFloat((data?.acceleration.x)! * 40)

                print(CGFloat((data?.acceleration.x)!))

            })

        }

player.position.x = destX
```

Originally I was moving the player using SKAction.moveTo but have removed this for testing purposes.

This works ok but the problem is, I have a sound that is being played upon collision of an invisible object and when this is enabled it sends the accelerometer all funny. There is no specific pattern to it but after a little while the player usually sticks to either side of the screen or just hovers in the middle and the accelerometer doesn't have any effect on the movement.

I am playing the sound using

```
let playSound = SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("phaserDown3.mp3", waitForCompletion: false)
```

At the top of the file and then calling run on a collision.

The full code is in here http://pastebin.com/f6kWTnr7 and I have made a little video of the issue here https://youtu.be/tcGYyrKE4QY - as you will see, in this case when the score is at around 15 it sticks to the left for a little bit, then returns to normal then sticks to the right. It isn't always at score 15, it can be sooner or even later there is no consistency at all.

Any input will be greatly appreciated, thank you in advance

Comment: whoa, you assign your accelerometerstart on update,  this is bad.  You only need to assign it once

Comment: Yeah, it is supposed to be done only once to be honest - I just moved it into update for testing purposes really, I have moved it back now

Comment: Here is a clean up of your code,  it is not tested so you will have to get it to compile:  http://pastebin.com/dxbRKqeh

Comment: Thank you for that - there are a few errors in there but I will work through those, I implemented your method for the accelerometer and this seems to work better but still the same issue occurs unfortunately

Comment: you also have the potential of playing sounds multiple times, do this 
`if !self.action(forKey:"phaser") {run(playSound,withKey:"phaser")}`

Comment: Ok - I have found that it's doing it with or without the sound, I have no idea what the issue is - just messes up the motion, something is clashing

Comment: did you implement my changes where nothing is in your update loop?

Comment: the only other slow down I am seeing is how you are making your blocks

Comment: Yep, I implemented those - I am just trying to debug now as we speak but so far nothing

Comment: I am doing another rewrite for you

Comment: Thank you so much for all your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this updated scene,  some of the major changes are I combined your 3 separate blocks into 1 SKNode so that I only have to move the single SKNode, and I set it up where you score at the end of a contact, not the beginning.  You can also see that the blocks now die when done scrolling, and your background is more efficient with its scrolling.  If you have any other questions on the changes, feel free to ask.

```
//
//  GameScene.swift
//  SpriteKitSimpleGame
//
//  Created by James Leist on 28/11/2016.
//  Copyright © 2016 James Leist. All rights reserved.
//

import SpriteKit
import CoreMotion

var motionManager = CMMotionManager()

enum BodyType:UInt32 {

    case player = 1
    case score = 2
    case dontCollide = 4
    case sides = 8

}

class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {
    var killNodes = [SKNode]()
    //let player = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Airplane")
    let player = SKSpriteNode(color: .green, size: CGSize(width:32,height:32))

    var bg1:SKSpriteNode!
    var bg2:SKSpriteNode!
    let block = SKNode()
    let blockHeight = 50
    var currentScore = 0
    var scoreLabel:SKLabelNode!
    let playSound = SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("phaserDown3.mp3", waitForCompletion: false)
    let move = SKAction.move(by:CGVector(dx:0,dy:-4 * 60),duration:1) //this means we move 4 every 1/60 of a second


    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {

        physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self
        backgroundColor = SKColor.white
        addScrollingBG()
        createRandomBlock()
        addRandomBlocks1()

        // sideRestraints()

        scoreLabel = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "Copperplate-Bold")
        scoreLabel.text = String(currentScore)
        scoreLabel.fontSize = 80
        scoreLabel.position = CGPoint(x: frame.size.width - 60, y: frame.size.height - 60)
        scoreLabel.zPosition = 20

        self.addChild(scoreLabel)
        player.name = "Player"
        player.zPosition = 15

        player.position = CGPoint(x: size.width * 0.5, y: size.height * 0.5)

        // player.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: SKTexture(imageNamed: "Airplane"), size: CGSize(width: player.size.width, height: player.size.height))

        player.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: CGSize(width: player.size.width, height: player.size.height))

        player.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
        player.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = BodyType.player.rawValue
        player.physicsBody!.contactTestBitMask = BodyType.score.rawValue | BodyType.sides.rawValue
        player.physicsBody!.collisionBitMask = 0


        addChild(player)

        startAccelerometer()

    }
    func startAccelerometer()
    {
        if motionManager.isAccelerometerAvailable == true {
            motionManager.startAccelerometerUpdates(to: OperationQueue.current!, withHandler: {
                [weak self]  data, error in

                guard let strongSelf = self else {return}
                var destX = UInt32(strongSelf.player.position.x + CGFloat((data?.acceleration.x)! * 40))
                // Called before each frame is rendered */

                if destX <= 0 {
                    destX = 0
                }
                else if destX >= UInt32(strongSelf.frame.size.width) {
                    destX = UInt32(strongSelf.frame.size.width)
                }

                strongSelf.player.position.x = CGFloat(destX)
                print(CGFloat((data?.acceleration.x)!))
            })

        }
    }
    func addScrollingBG() {

        bg1 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "bgPlayScene")
        bg1 = SKSpriteNode(color:.blue,size:self.size)

        bg1.anchorPoint = CGPoint.zero
        bg1.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
        // bg1.size = CGSize(width: frame.size.width, height: frame.size.height)
        bg1.zPosition = 0
        addChild(bg1)

        bg2 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "bgPlayScene")
        bg2 = SKSpriteNode(color:.purple,size:self.size)

        bg2.anchorPoint = CGPoint.zero
        bg2.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: bg1.size.height)
        // bg2.size = CGSize(width: frame.size.width, height: frame.size.height)
        bg2.zPosition = 0
        self.addChild(bg2)
        setupBackgroundAnimation()


    }

    func setupBackgroundAnimation()
    {
        let reset = SKAction.customAction(withDuration: 1,actionBlock:
            {
                node,time in
                guard let sNode = node as? SKSpriteNode else {return}
                sNode.position = sNode.position.y <= -sNode.size.height ?
                    CGPoint(x: sNode.position.x, y: sNode.position.y + sNode.size.height * 2) : sNode.position
        })

        let scroll = SKAction.repeatForever(SKAction.group([move,reset]))
        bg1.run(scroll)
        bg2.run(scroll)



    }
    func createRandomBlock()
    {
        block.position = CGPoint(x:0,y:size.height + CGFloat(blockHeight))

        //let partialBlock = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "block")
        let partialBlock = SKSpriteNode(color:.yellow, size:CGSize(width: 1, height: blockHeight))

        let blockLeft1 = partialBlock.copy() as! SKSpriteNode
        blockLeft1.name = "left"
        blockLeft1.anchorPoint = CGPoint.zero

        blockLeft1.size = CGSize(width: 1, height: blockHeight)
        blockLeft1.zPosition = 5;
        blockLeft1.position = CGPoint.zero
        block.addChild(blockLeft1)

        let leftBody =  SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: blockLeft1.size)
        leftBody.affectedByGravity = false
        leftBody.categoryBitMask = BodyType.sides.rawValue
        leftBody.contactTestBitMask = 0
        leftBody.collisionBitMask = 0
        leftBody.isDynamic = false
        blockLeft1.physicsBody = leftBody

        let blockRight1 = partialBlock.copy() as! SKSpriteNode
        blockRight1.color = .green
        blockRight1.anchorPoint = CGPoint.zero
        blockRight1.name = "right"

        blockRight1.size = CGSize(width: 1, height: blockHeight)
        blockRight1.zPosition = 5;
        blockRight1.position = CGPoint(x:size.width,y:0)
        block.addChild(blockRight1)

        let rightBody =  SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: blockRight1.size)
        rightBody.affectedByGravity = false
        rightBody.categoryBitMask = BodyType.sides.rawValue
        rightBody.contactTestBitMask = 0
        rightBody.collisionBitMask = 0
        rightBody.isDynamic = false
        blockRight1.physicsBody = rightBody

        let scoreBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf:CGSize(width:Int(frame.size.width),height:blockHeight))
        scoreBody.affectedByGravity = false
        scoreBody.categoryBitMask = BodyType.score.rawValue
        scoreBody.contactTestBitMask = 0
        scoreBody.collisionBitMask = 0
        scoreBody.isDynamic = false
        block.physicsBody = scoreBody
    }
    func addRandomBlocks1() {

        let randomLeftWidth : UInt32  = arc4random_uniform(UInt32(size.width) - 50)

        let randomRightWidth  : UInt32 = arc4random_uniform((UInt32(size.width) - randomLeftWidth) - 50)

        guard let newBlock = block.copy() as? SKNode else {return} //ifw e do not have a node return
        if let leftBlock = newBlock.childNode(withName:"left") as? SKSpriteNode
        {
            leftBlock.xScale = CGFloat(randomLeftWidth)

        }
        if let rightBlock = newBlock.childNode(withName:"right") as? SKSpriteNode
        {
            rightBlock.xScale = -CGFloat(randomRightWidth)
        }

        let addRandom = SKAction.customAction(withDuration: 0, actionBlock:
            {
                [unowned self] node,time in
                if Int(node.position.y) < -self.blockHeight
                {
                    node.removeFromParent()
                    self.addRandomBlocks1()

                }
        })

        newBlock.run(SKAction.repeatForever(SKAction.group([move,addRandom])))

        addChild(newBlock)

    }


    override func update(_ currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {

    }
    override func didFinishUpdate()
    {
        killNodes.forEach{$0.removeFromParent()}
    }


    func didBegin(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {

        //This will organize the bodies so that the lowest category is A
        let bodies = (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask <= contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask) ? (A:contact.bodyA,B:contact.bodyB) : (A:contact.bodyB,B:contact.bodyA)


        switch (bodies.A.categoryBitMask,bodies.B.categoryBitMask)
        {
            case let (a, b) where ((a & BodyType.player.rawValue) | (b & BodyType.sides.rawValue)) > 0:
                killNodes.append(bodies.A.node!)
                let label = SKLabelNode(text: "Gameover")
                label.position = CGPoint(x:self.size.width/2,y:self.size.height/2)
                addChild(label)
            default:()

        }


    }
    func didEnd(_ contact: SKPhysicsContact) {

        //This will organize the bodies so that the lowest category is A
        let bodies = (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask <= contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask) ? (A:contact.bodyA,B:contact.bodyB) : (A:contact.bodyB,B:contact.bodyA)


        switch (bodies.A.categoryBitMask,bodies.B.categoryBitMask)
        {
        case let (a, b) where ((a & BodyType.player.rawValue) | (b & BodyType.score.rawValue)) > 0:
            currentScore += 1
            run(playSound, withKey:"phaser")

            scoreLabel.text = String(currentScore)
        default:()

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks - it seems to be working now, I changed the motion also to use func processUserMotion(forUpdate currentTime: CFTimeInterval) and it is much more stable now

Comment: if you are doing that then do not have the handler running

Comment: I am running motionManager.startAccelerometerUpdates() earlier on in the script and it seems to be working really well now

Comment: Yes, that should only be called once